# Catch DragEnter and DragDrop events on webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I have TreeView, ListView and WebBrowser controls. I use the drag and drop method. With the TreeView and ListView everything works, because they have Dragdrop and DragEnter event.
But I did not find them in WebBrowser.

I try using:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.Drag += new HtmlElementEventHandler(WebBrowser_Drag);
webBrowser1.Document.Body.DragOver += new HtmlElementEventHandler(WebBrowser_DragOver);
webBrowser1.Document.Body.DragEnd += new HtmlElementEventHandler(WebBrowser_DragEnd);
webBrowser1.Document.Body.DragLeave += new HtmlElementEventHandler(WebBrowser_DragLeave);
```

The DragOver and DragLeave events triggered, but it is not possible to change the cursor like

```
e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
```

The Drag and DragEnd events is not triggered.

I also try:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.AttachEventHandler("dragdrop", WebBrowser_DragDrop);
webBrowser1.Document.AttachEventHandler("dragdrop", WebBrowser_DragDrop);
webBrowser1.Document.AttachEventHandler("ondrop", WebBrowser_OnDrop);
webBrowser1.Document.Body.AttachEventHandler("ondrop", WebBrowser_OnDrop);
```

but it does not work well.

Now I have some questions:

1. How to change the cursor in the event DragOver and DragLeave.
2. Is there a way to process data as well as Dragdrop and DragEnter for WebBrowser?

Comment: They don't work at all like the normal desktop D+D events, you are supposed to manipulate the DOM yourself.  Best starting point is to work from Javascript sample code.  Try a google query like "javascript ondragenter getdata".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Changing the cursor here [Change webbrowser Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858606/change-webbrowser-cursor). But among the possible cursors unfortunately no draganddrop cursor.
2. The easiest way to solve my problem that I have found is to use a transparent panel [Clearing the graphics of a transparent panel C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798105/clearing-the-graphics-of-a-transparent-panel-c-sharp):

   ```
   private void WebBrowser_DragOver(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
   {
       panel.BringToFront();
   }

   private void Panel_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       panel.SendToBack();
   }

   private void Panel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       panel.SendToBack();
   }

   private void Panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
   }

   private void Panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       //Make dragdrop data processing
   }
   ```

Comment: [Looking for windows drag and drop cursors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487213/3110834)