# Change webbrowser Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a form that contains WebBrowser control.
I need to change the cursor to WebBrowser.

I try

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
this.TopLevelControl.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

The cursor changes form only, but not for WebBrowser.

How can I change the cursor in WebBrowser control?

Comment: WebBrowser control does not support the Cursor property.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You must change the cursor from within the displayed web page (CSS: `body { cursor: wait; }`).

Comment: What if the cursor is set by HTML document via CSS, like @AndreiV pointed out? Are you trying to override this behavior?

Comment: In my tests, setting the cursor directly in the web page works as requested. That can only be used when you have direct access to all the pages that will ever be loaded. I don't know if and how you can inject such a rule (without parsing the source and setting it "by hand").

Comment: Is there a way to set (CSS: body {cursor: wait;}) without reloading the page to the position of scrollbars, selected and entered text is not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to your solution to "mshtml.dll". After you load your `Document`, try this:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (webDocument1.Document.DomDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
IHTMLStyleSheet style = doc.createStyleSheet("", 0);
style.cssText = @"body { cursor: wait; }";
```

Please bear in mind that the result depends also on the way you load the web page (load a local/embedded file, set the `DocumentStream`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, it really helped, no page reload. How can I remove the installed cssStyle "body {cursor: wait;}"?

Comment: @Nikolay, if you want to set the cursor back to the default arrow, just use `style.cssText = @"body { cursor: default; }";`:

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for Failure:**

you are setting the Cursor for `Form` Instead of `WebBrowser` Control as below:

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

thats why it is setting the cursor to `Form` instead of `WebBrowser` Control.

you can set the Cursor for any Control as below:

```
controlName.Cursor=System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

but `WebBrowser` control does not support the Cursor property.
hence you can not set this property for `WebBrowser` Control.even if you set it, it does not give compile errors but throws following Runtime Error.

```
WebBrowser Control does not Support the Cursor Property.
```

Comment: This doesn't answers the question *How can I change the cursor in WebBrowser control?*.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cursor of a Form with a WebBrowser control in it, the Form will show the wait cursor, but the browser will not, because the browser sets the cursor on it's own corresponding to the HTML content. For example if you move the mouse over a hyperlink, Internet Explorer changes the cursor to the hand cursor. Also JavaScript and CSS can modify the cursor. So there is no way to set a WaitCursor while Internet Explorer is controling the cursor.

But I found a trick to do this with one line of code!

If you do a lengthy processing and want to display the wait cursor meanwhile, you can use this code to turn it on and off:

```
    public void SetWaitCursor(bool b_Wait)
    {
        Application.UseWaitCursor = b_Wait;

        // The Browser control must be disabled otherwise it does not show the wait cursor.
        webBrowser.Enabled = !b_Wait;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

The trick is disabling the browser control and it will show the Wait Cursor because a disabled Internet Explorer does not control the cursor anymore.

So your final code will look like this:

```
SetWaitCursor(true);

doLenghtyProcessing();

SetWaitCursor(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Icon ico = new Icon(@"C:\temp\someIcon.ico");
this.Cursor = new Cursor(ico.Handle);
The static class System.Windows.Forms.Cursors contains all system cursors.
To switch back to the default system cursor, use this:

this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
```